# Ajax request inside an other ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, include

So i made an ajax request for get my "home" page and my "about" page in a "container" on click menu link button inside my index.php, and now i have three link in my "home" page, and i also want open each of these links inside my div "container" to replace the "home" page, so how can i make an ajax request after the first ajax call ?

This is my php request in the index.php:

```html
<div id="container">
   <?php
    $d="contenu/";
    if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    $p=strtolower($_GET['p']);
    if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/",$p) && file_exists($d.$p.".html")){
        include $d.$p.".html";
    }
  else{
   include "pages/404.html";
  }
  }
   else{
   include "pages/home.html";
  }
   ?>
</div>
```

In here my ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu a").click(function(){
        page=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/"+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                afficher(html);
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                afficher("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
 
});

function afficher(data){
$("#container").fadeOut(500,function(){
    $("#container").empty();
    $("#container").append(data);
    $("#container").fadeIn(1200);
 
});
}
```

and finally my home.html ( i just show you the links ):

```html
<div class="section vs-section" data-speed="0.4">
            <div class="vs-transform title " data-speed="0.4"><a href="projet1.html"><h3>projet1</h3></a></div>
            <div class="vs-transform title" data-speed="0.38"><a href="projet2.html"><h3>Projet2</h3></a></div>
            <div class="vs-transform title" data-speed="0.4"><a href="projet3.html"><h3>projet3</h3></a></div>

  </div>
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for event delegation for the click handler.

Comment: my actual ajax is calling by "menu a" button, making the request php, now i want to know if i can get a new ajax on "vs-transform a" button when the first ajax is already interpreted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, you should just use event delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to deal with the new HTML tags added dynamically to the DOM by the first ajax request :

```
$('body').on('click', '.vs-transform a', function(){
     //Second ajax request
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes perfect thank you and yes actually @Felix Kling you were right.